What is electrical work divided by charge?
Electrical work is the difference in two electric potential energies. Is electrical work / charge:
Electric potential
OR
Electric potential difference (a difference in two electric potentials)?
My understanding is that electric potential is actually potential energy / charge, so electric potential difference would be delta potential energy / charge, which is equal to work / charge.
However, sources like wikipedia say:

Electric potential ... is defined as the amount of work/energy needed per unit of electric charge

They are saying work / charge = electric potential instead of electric potential difference.

The question is easily answered by cobsulting a textbook on E&M.

Learn physics from textbooks with good reputation. Wikipedia is quite bad on physics, and the quotation on electric potential does not deviate from this expectation.

@JánLalinský I appreciate the comments saying to consult a textbook, but why not just state what the answer is? Is it electric potential or electric potential difference? If this is such a trivial question why not just answer it off the top of your head?

I don't know what you mean by "electric work", I don't think in such terms. Do you mean work of electric field force on a charged particle? In general such work is not expressible in terms of electric potential. Electric potential describes only part of  net electric field, the conservative part.

Or do you mean work of a battery in a circuit? This is not the same thing as work of electric field force.

I think that your understanding (potential difference = work / charge) is not in contradiction with what Wikipedia says: electrostatic potential is defined as the amount of work/energy needed per unit of electric charge to move the charge from a reference point to a specific point in an electric field. The key to see this are the words reference point because from the Wikipedia definition it follows that the electrostetic potential at the reference point is zero. So if we move the charge from the reference point to a specific point the potential difference equals the potential at the specific point. If the charge is moved beteween two generic points (e.g. not starting from the reference point), then it is important to use the potential difference.
As noted in the comment when the fields aren't static things get more complicated.
